# WPF DataGrid sort columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

By default, it is set so that you can sort the columns of a DataGrid by clicking on the headers.
During programming the behavior of my program has changed so that I can not sort the columns. I do not know what has caused this.
XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="ReportTool.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle}" Height="306.716" MaxHeight="350" Width="495.149" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<ScrollViewer >
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridAusgabe" CanUserSortColumns="True" Loaded="DataGridAusgabe_Loaded_1" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is how I bind to DataGrid:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string path = "adressen.txt";

    StreamReader sr;
    ObservableCollection<String[]> line_list = new ObservableCollection<String[]>();
    ObservableCollection<String[]> output_data = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReadFile(path);
    }

    void ReadFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);
            while (true)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line != "")
                {
                    if (line == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    line_list.Add(line.Split(','));
                    output_data.Add(line.Split(','));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            this.Close();
        }

        DataGridAusgabe.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataGridAusgabe.Columns.Clear();
        var ifaConv = new ItemFromArrayConverter();
        int k = 0;
        foreach (var header in output_data.First())
        {
            DataGridAusgabe.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = header,
                Binding = new Binding() { Converter = ifaConv, ConverterParameter = k++ },
            });
        }
        DataGridAusgabe.ItemsSource = output_data.Skip(1);
    }

    public class ItemFromArrayConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Member
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var arr = (object[])value;
            return arr[int.Parse(parameter.ToString())];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough details. Are you getting to see your data in grid at all?
Looking at binding, seems you are not providing the input data (the binding path).

Comment: @ManishBasantani Yes I can see my data in the Grid.

Comment: @ManishBasantani I fill the Collection "output_data" before by reading a textfile. But this is not the point.

Comment: @ManishBasantani see one more my c# code